# Problemas con los exponentes en el label de python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Deseo colocar como leyenda la siguiente formula:

10-3 Wm-2

donde el -3 y el -2 quiero ponerlos como exponentes.

por ejemplo uso:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
y=[0.020,0.300,0.450,0.500]
x=[1,2,3,4]
plt.plot(x,y,'-',color='darkred')
plt.xlabel('Dias')
plt.ylabel('$10^-3Wm^-2$')
plt.show()
```

Pero no obtengo lo deseado.

¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: La pregunta es buenísima, y podrías ayudar a muchas personas en el futuro, pero como es posible que la hayas formulado tan mal... teniendo ya tanta experiencia en el sitio... Por favor, agrega el código completo, el error que te da o la solución que tienes y lo que te gustaría tener, así cómo ser más específico y poner algo como: "¿Cómo poner labels en Latex en matplotlib?" por ejemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quizas esta Documentacion te ayude. Es para hacer text rendering en lenguag20es como LaTex en titulos de figura, ejes...

[Writing mathematical expressions](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/mathtext.html)

En mi caso, he reproducido el siguient script. Las formulas se ponen dentro de `r'$  formula $'`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3],label=r'$10^{-3}Wm^{-2}$')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Y me produce la siguiente figura
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Es necesario definir una cadena como "raw-string", de forma que no considere los caracteres de escape y reconoce el '$' como caracter de definición de LaTeX.

```
plt.label(r'$10^-3Wm^-2$')
plt.show()
```

De esta forma puedes especificar ecuaciones completas (puedes utilizar como referencia http://www.hostmath.com/ para la edición de LaTeX).